# looking for opensource software like scholar one or editorial manager

Tags: open-source, php

is there any open source software available for publishing houses like the editorial manager or scholar one?

I preferred os oracle Linux(self-hosted)
to store bucket s3
crossref plagarism checker
doi id assignment for published article and report
orc id login

user's role
author,
editors,
admin
EIC who will finally approve open access
subscribers with a membership cost
the reviewer can add comments and based on the comments authors will be able to resubmit that manuscript
after acceptance, they will be able to show the manuscript online in HTML format and pdf

authors will be able to check the status and they will receive during the peer-review process using amazon SES email notifications
subscriber will receive published article
open access to the journal will be provided to the paid author while the journal will be published finally by EIC(editor in chief's) approval

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: what features are needed, what's your price margin (how much may it cost).

Comment: @lzzy  updated as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks! As you did not mention the cost factor, I assume you mean "open source & free of charge"? And using the `php` tag implies self-hosted? The previous-to-last paragraph is a bit hard to understand, too (grammar-wise; is there a colon missing after "editors"?) – but maybe they are clear to someone familiar with the topic.